# SQL Profiles showing high activity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance

I am running my application locally -- ie. No external traffic and very low number of queries, fully under my control. I see tons of 'Audit Login' and 'Audit Logout' events. What are these and where are they actually stored (ie. Where is this audit log)? Are these a hint of a problem with connections, because I have only a simple connection string within my app and thought that connections would remain active throughout the operation of my app (ie. a single login at launch, and then a single logout when terminating).

Comment: I also get an odd sp_reset_connection re-occuring -- any ideas what this one is?

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279401/sql-connection-pooling-and-audit-login-logout

Answer (score 1):

Audit Login is an "[Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175481.aspx)" exposed through the SQL Server Profiler tool. It is not a physical audit trail, i.e. this Event Class data is not recorded within a database table some place within SQL Server.

The event will fire each time SQL Server needs to authenticate a new SQL Server Login or when an existing connection is reused from a connection pool.

See [Audit Login Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190260.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ASP.NET connection pooling? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.71).aspx. Active connections can be pooled within ASP.NET so that when a database operation needs to be done, a connection to the database does not have to be established, but rather re-used.

The audit events are probably related to this. SQL Server audits login and logout. You may be able to configure this behaviour, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850.aspx.