# Audit login and logout using EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with .NET 4.6.2 in my system
when I profile I saw the audit login audit logout more then few times

[image]
as you can see in the picture , sometimes this process can take 1 second.

I read this post "[SQL Connection Pooling and Audit Login/Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279401/sql-connection-pooling-and-audit-login-logout)" but it doesn't helps me bacuse I'm using EF and working with few contexts DBs
and using the keyword `USE` can't help me here.
I tried also working change the Max Pool Dize, but didn't do much to the performance of the login and logout durations